# Spring OXM doesn't work with Struts 1

Tags: java, spring, struts-1, spring-oxm

I use `Spring OXM` as well as `Struts 1` but without using integrating Struts with Spring IOC. This is because the application is an old one and I'm just adding a module that involves the XML binding and I have no intention to change the architecture of the application.

I have an action class calls `ClasspathXmlApplicationContext` for bean injection for the OXM.

Here is my spring context XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-1.5.xsd">

    <bean id="xmlMapper" class="com.st.mas.wmr.utils.xml.stifbinconv.XmlMapper">
        <property name="marshaller" ref="jaxbMarshaller" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="jaxbMarshaller" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="contextPath" value="com.st.mas.wmr.utils.xml.jaxb.stifbinconv"/>
        <property name="validating" value="true"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The action class:

```
public class StifBinConversionAction extends AnyDispatchAction {
    private IProcessStifOliBinConversion svc;

    public StifBinConversionAction() {
        super();
        svc = new ProcessStifOliBinConversion();
    }
```

The service class:

```
public class ProcessStifOliBinConversion
    implements
        IProcessStifOliBinConversion {
    private BasicDataSource ds;

    private IAtomStifOliBinConversion dao;
    private ApplicationContext ctx;
    private XmlMapper xmlMapper;

    public ProcessStifOliBinConversion() {
        super();
        ds = new BasicDataSource();
        //TODO consts
        ds.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@sglx482:1521:wmr");
        ds.setUsername("wmr_online");
        ds.setPassword("wmr_online");

        dao = new AtomStifOliBinConversion(ds);
        ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/st/mas/wmr/utils/xml/stifbinconv/oxm-context.xml");
        xmlMapper = ctx.getBean(XmlMapper.class);
    }
```

The web application gives `HTTP 500` **WITHOUT** any error message or stack trace. However, if I change the config location of the `ClasspathXmlApplicationContext` to an invalid one, Spring throws an exception.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [classes/com/st/mas/wmr/utils/xml/stifbinconv/oxm-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [classes/com/st/mas/wmr/utils/xml/stifbinconv/oxm-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Seems that the problem is within the Spring injection.

It's irritating when there's an error but there's no error message. It makes you stuck for days.

Thanks

Will

Answer (score 1):

> It's irritating when there's an error
>   but there's no error message. It makes
>   you stuck for days.

??? There *is* an error message: your XML can't be found at this location:

```
classes/com/st/mas/wmr/utils/xml/stifbinconv/oxm-context.xml
```

I'd say you are passing bad parameters to the `ApplicationContext`. Take a look at the example in [4.7.1.1 Constructing ClassPathXmlApplicationContext instances - shortcuts](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-app-ctx-classpathxml)

> Consider a directory layout that
>   looks like this:

```
com/
  foo/
    services.xml
    daos.xml
    MessengerService.class
```

> A ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
>   instance composed of the beans defined
>   in the 'services.xml' and 'daos.xml'
>   could be instantiated like so...

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
    new String[] {"services.xml", "daos.xml"}, MessengerService.class
```

Perhaps you should also use that Pattern with [this Constructor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html#ClassPathXmlApplicationContext%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29):

```
ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("oxm-context.xml", XmlMapper.class);
```

Comment: Reread my original post: The web application gives HTTP 500 WITHOUT any error message or stack trace. However, if I change the config location of the ClasspathXmlApplicationContext to an invalid one, Spring throws an exception.